# Print the 10 best results of a txt file

Tags: c, scanf, fopen

I can't find a way to solve this one.

I have a text file like this : score.txt

```
pat 20
ananna 20
radis 19
```

The number of lines can be between 10 and anything.

My goal is to print the 10 line where the integers are the higher, in order.

I tried with this, but I can't even read the number in my text file.

```
void fillScore(){
    FILE* f =NULL;
    f= fopen("score.txt", "r");
    char name[20];
    int score,i,j,tmp;
    int tabScore[10]={-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
    char tabName[10][20];
    if (f==NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while(fscanf(f,"%s%d",name,&score)==1){
        printf("TEST : %d - ",score);
        for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            if(score>tabScore[i]){
                tmp=tabScore[i];
                tabScore[i]=score;
                for(j=i+1;j<10;j++){
                    score=tabScore[j];
                    tabScore[j]=tmp;
                    tmp=score;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            printf("%d\n",tabScore[i]);
    }
    

    fclose(f);
}
```

Does anybody have a hint on this ? I can get how to do it. I know it's not a great question, because it shows a lack of research, but I swear that I search on the web for hours.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: From `man fscanf`: on success, these functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned; this can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure. Probably `== 1` is not what you want

Comment: If this is not a homework question, I would use different tools that are made for these kind of things, for example, `perl -ne '/(\d+)/; $t = $_ ;for (0..9) { if ($s[$_]->[0] < $1) { splice(@s, $_, 0, [$1, $t]); last } }; END { print map { $_->[1] } @s[0..9] }' < file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're testing `fscanf` against the wrong value `1`.

As per man page,

> on success, these functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned; this can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure

Since you're asking `*scanf()` to convert two items, you want to check its  return value against `2`.

The following works:

```
...
while(fscanf(f,"%s%d",name,&score) == 2){
...
```